# Get search service Application name via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write some automated scripts to update the web.config, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Modification to the Web.config can best be done by using the [SPWebConfigModification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification(v=office.15).aspx) class in for example a feature activation event. This way you ensure that the modifications are done througout the whole farm.

[SPMatt](http://spmatt.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/using-spwebconfigmodification-to-update-the-web-config-in-sharepoint-2013/) describes a nice example how this can be done.